# excel freezes while entering data

Tags: excel, freeze, vba

I have this excel file and it freezes when I'm entering data. For instance, I double click on a cell, enter the data and when I press " enter ". It freezes instead of going to the cell underneath. Pressing " enter " several times doesn't unfreeze the program, the only thing that works is selecting another cell with the mouse.

This excel sheet has more or less 10 sheets and I have two or three macros but this problem persists even when I'm disabling the macros.

I have tried to run this excel file on two different Macs and both of them experience the same problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you can select another cell with the mouse, it doesn't sound frozen. When this happens, go to File - Options - Advanced and check the "After pressing Enter, move selection" property. You expect a checked box and Down, but if it's unchecked, then we know the 'what' if not the 'why'

Comment: Ok I'll be more precise, my excel is configured to go to the cell underneath the active cell after pressing excel.

So, when I select a cell a blue halo appears around it, I enter a number (the blue halo disappears while entering the number this is normal), I press enter and the blue halo does not appear on the cell beneath (excel is semi - frozen). If I click on the navigation bar for example instead of another cell, excel unfreezes and the halo appears on the cell below.

Answer (score 11):

Disable Flash fill under file > options > advanced > editing options > "automatically flash fill" This is a known issue with Excel!

Answer (score 1):

Saving the workbook in an older version enabled me to enter data without the workbook freezing.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue happen to me today.
I was editing an Excel workbook that had cells referenced in another workbook that was open at the time.
When I entered a value, the worksheet I was on would not respond, going to another worksheet and entering a value then escaping would "reset" and I would be able to go back to the worksheet to resume work, but would get "stuck" again right after entering another value.

Solved the issue by closing the other Excel workbook that was referencing cells in the workbook I was working on.